# WPF Hiding the First Item of an ItemsControl (Combobox,textbox,etc)

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to hide the first item's (combobox)control in an itemscontrol in xaml in pure view only ?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QueueConditionCollection.Collection,
              NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
              AlternationCount="2">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <ComboBox Name="cmbLogicalOperator" 
                ItemsSource="{BindingLogicalOperatorCollection.Collection}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding LogicalOperatorCollection.Selected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Actual Scenario:
Hide the the control if the collection has only 1 item:
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGwET.png).

Comment: You will have to bind different collections to do so. Why do you want to hide the first item if I may ask? What is the scenario here?

Comment: updating the question @RavirajPalvankar

Comment: Your "actual scenario" seems to be different. If there's more than 1 item do you hide the itemscontrol?

Comment: You can declare a boolean property which will return false if Collection.Count() == 1 and use a boolean to visibility converter for your combo box.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar done updating.. not the entire item.. but one control only

Comment: @Andy  thanks for that yes your'e correct i want to hide it

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar thanks.. I applied your suggestion

Comment: Great, I've posted it as answer, do mark answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a boolean property which will return false if Collection.Count() == 1 and use a boolean to visibility converter for your combo box

Comment: thank for your suggestion bro.. No other way but to create a property in ViewModel

Comment: Other than a datatrigger bound to items.count.